# Chromecast Custom Receiver with YouTube Iframe API showing banner ads that can't be closed

Tags: chromecast, youtube-iframe-api

So we are working on developing a ChromeCast custom receiver app and we are using the YouTube iFrame API for loading YT videos. The issue is that we are seeing the banner ads across the bottom while they are playing on the ChromeCast. Obviously, there is no way for the user to interact with or close this ad while the video is being cast to the ChromeCast. Does anyone know if there is a way to disable these ads types when the video is being cast? I understand that the ads are controlled by the content owner, but it seems there would be a more effective ad then one that a user can't even click through to on the ChromeCast.